# Remove UILabel from superview

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

I have an application that is written in Rubymotion. I am adding a label to the subView of the view. When I first call my method I want to remove any UILabel's form the superView so I can write new text over that same position.

```
class CalorieIntakeController < UIViewController
  @label = UILabel.new

  @label.frame = [[0,270],[self.view.frame.size.width, 50]]
  @label.text = "Text goes here"
  self.view.addSubview(@label)
end
```

I am trying to figure out how to use ruby to find if there is already a UILabel present.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [RMQ](https://github.com/infinitered/rmq) if you are going to be doing much of this. The code would be far simpler. Example:

```
view.parent.find(UILabel).attr(text: '') # Sets all UILabels below parent to blank
```

or, if you're bent on removing the labels:

```
view.parent.find(UILabel).remove         # Removes all UILabels below parent
```

If you really want to know whether there was a `UILabel` present in the first place, just use the selector:

```
view.parent.find(UILabel).length
```

That will come up zero if none are there, otherwise you'll have a count of labels in the parent view.

This is not an exact answer to your question, but rather an alternative way to accomplish the task you're describing. Using stylesheets, you can clear a bunch of setup stuff out of your controller code and put it in styles. Then you can act by hiding, showing, inserting, or removing various UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to clear the text of the label or you can hide and then make it visible instead of adding and removing the view.